# Expo Push Notification for iOS standalone app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, expo

I am currently following this [guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/guides/push-notifications) to enable push notifications via Exponent. Since I do not currently have a physical iOS device (bought one and waiting for it to arrive) I cannot but wonder whether Push Notifications work when I build the application as standalone and ship it to Apple Store.

The reason I am asking this question is because in the [next section](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/guides/using-fcm) of the Expo guide, it says that for Android standalone apps, one needs to upload the FCM credentials. Then it also says that FCM is not currently supported for Expo iOS. This is really not clear - does it mean that once an Expo app is built as standalone and uploaded to Apple Store, the push notifications won't work, or?

Does anyone has similar experience that can shed some light one this?